# Open html page inside odoo 9 module

Tags: html, odoo, odoo-9

I have one html page (css,js) how add this html page in custom module and link to menu.

After click on menu (backend) link I need open html page in popup html.

Any example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
        <data>
            <record id="test_check" model="ir.actions.act_url">
                <field name="name">Test</field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.act_url</field>
                <field name="target">new</field>
                <field name="url">test/static/src/index.html?</field>
        </record>



        <menuitem action="test_check" name="Test" id="menu_test_check" sequence="44"/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

When use **new** html page is open in new tab, I want after open eg. Accounting after click in menu link in small window (200 x 200px) open html page. In my example in html page I have calculator. Example [postimg.org/image/jzll39dp5](https://postimg.org/image/jzll39dp5/)

Is it possible implement this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2

Answer (score 1):

> Create an action and add it in menu

eg:-

> Create an action to open a html page.

```
<record id="google_check" model="ir.actions.act_url">
                <field name="name">Google</field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.act_url</field>
                <field name="target">new</field>
                <field name="url">https://www.google.com.in/?</field>
        </record>



<menuitem action="google_check" name="Google" id="menu_google_check" parent="purchase.menu_procurement_management"/>
```

Comment: Tnx for help, your example work fine but is it possible open html page in popup window.

Comment: field name="target" used  for open in current or new like popup Please check this .https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/actions.html

Comment: Tnx but this option can't solve my problem. When use new html page is open in new tab, I want after open eg. Accounting after click in menu link in small window (200 x 200px) open html page. In my example in html page I have calculator. Example https://postimg.org/image/jzll39dp5/

Answer (score 1):

If you need a "website menu" link then you have to do this

https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/10.0/addons/website/data/website_data.xml#L17

What you see there is the menu entry for the homepage. You can link whatever you want in the "url" field.

Comment: Tnx for answer, I need link in backend, below answer Vishnu Loyal work fine but open html page in new tab is it possible open in popup window?